# Magento 2.1.9 : Cart Rules (Please enter a valid date)

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have the this started after **upgrading from CE2.1.7 to CE2.1.8**, Currently my version in CE 2.1.9 but still getting the same issue.

**Default Country Spain** and **locale United Kingdom** for now.

**=> Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be locale specific issue. try to create same rule after setting english locale .
 for reference you may check this issue on git https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10686

Comment: I see that issue, but without change Locale how it's possible? Because if I have 2 many website and store available for a different country so how it possible.